# How to Pass Data from Next.js Middleware to getServerSideProps in the Initial Request? (with cookies)

Tags: javascript, next.js, cookies, server-side-rendering

I'm facing an issue in a Next.js application (for a code callenge)

Here's the general flow I'm asked to achieve, specifically:

1. In Next middleware function, check if a cookie with geolocation data exists. If not, make a call to get the data and store it in a cookie.
2. In `getServerSideProps`, utilize the cookie (if available) to pass geolocation data as a prop to my component.

My current implementation sets the cookie in middleware but getServerSideProps cannot access it during the initial render/request. If I refresh the page/subsequent calls, I can read the cookie in SSR no problem.

**ChatGPT says that:**

> When the user first visits the site, your middleware correctly
> identifies that there is no cookie set, fetches the geolocation data,
> and sets the cookie in the response. The issue arises in that during
> this initial visit, the getServerSideProps function runs after the
> middleware but before the cookie can be received by the client and
> sent back with subsequent requests.

Below is the relevant portion of my code:

**Middleware:**

```
export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  console.log('Middleware execution!')
  if (req.cookies.has(USER_GEOLOCATION_DATA_COOKIE_KEY)) {
    console.log('Middleware: Cookie detected')
    NextResponse.next()
  } else {
    console.log('Middleware: executing call!')
    const response = NextResponse.next()
    let userGeolocationData = await getUserGeolocationData()
    console.log('Has already finished call')
    response.cookies.set(
      USER_GEOLOCATION_DATA_COOKIE_KEY,
      JSON.stringify(userGeolocationData),
    )
    return response
  }
}
```

**ServerSideProps of index page:**

```
export const getServerSideProps = (async ({ req }) => {
  const userGeolocationDataCookie =
    req.cookies[USER_GEOLOCATION_DATA_COOKIE_KEY]

  let userGeolocationData

  if (userGeolocationDataCookie) {
    console.log('Habemus cookie SSR')
    userGeolocationData = JSON.parse(userGeolocationDataCookie)
  } else {
    console.log('NO COOKIE SSR')
    userGeolocationData = null
  }

  return {
    props: { userGeolocationData },
  }
}) satisfies GetServerSideProps<RootPageProps>
```

**Constraint:** One can suggest that if I can't get the cookie in SSR, then I should fetch the geolocationData and return that, ensuring that the data will be sent first render. However, we discussed with the interviewer that in that case, in the initial render, I will make 2 calls, one in middleware and one in SSR. So if a million users request our page then 2 millions call will be made. So I need to look an efficient way to solve this.

There is a potential solution?